# Unable change the state in componentDidMount properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm doing my project in react using firebase.The code is as below

```
var storage = firebase.storage()
var storageRef = storage.ref();

export default class WallPics extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            images : []
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        var imgArr=[]
        storageRef.listAll()
            .then(allPics=>{
                allPics.items.forEach(function (picRef){
                   picRef.getDownloadURL()
                    .then(function (url){
                        imgArr.push(
                            <img src={url} alt="pics" />
                        )
                    })

                })
                this.setState({
                    images : imgArr
                })  
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.images}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In above code I'm getting all of my pictures references from my firebase storage and appending the picture download URLs to the `imgArr`.After appending all URLs to the `imgArr` I want to change the state.But here `this.setState` is getting empty `imgArr`.But I want to change the state value with `imgArr` with picture download URLs.How can I do that now?

Comment: `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: I tried both.But none are working.

Comment: In your code you will first call setState and then your array will be filled.
This is beacause your will fill your array async `picRef.getDownloadURL()`. Have a look to the `Promise.all` implementation.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, you might check my answer as a little supplement =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't suggest you to put the component directly into state, according to React official documents [here](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-should-go-in-state):

> State should contain data that a component's event handlers may change to trigger a UI update.

It also clearly stated that **components** should not go in state:

> this.state should only contain the minimal amount of data needed to represent your UI's state. As such, it should not contain:
>
> **React components**: Build them in render() based on underlying props and
> state.

Thus, I suggest you to first extract the fetch action to a separate function for better reading and set the urls you need to state, instead of the component.

```
fetchPics = async() => {
  const allPics = await storageRef.listAll();
  const allUrls = await allPics.items.map(picRef => picRef.getDownloadURL());
  // here I use async, you might also use promise.all() 
  // as stated in @Alexandr Zavalii's answer
  this.setState({ images : allUrls })
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchPics();
}
```

Finally, render the components with the urls in the render function.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.images.map(url => <img src={url} alt="pics" />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is getDownloadURL asynchronous? if yes then you should wait for promises to resolve

Try something like this?

```
async componentDidMount() {
   let imgArr=[]
   let allPics = await storageRef.listAll()
   let promises = []
   allPics.items.forEach((picRef) => {
       promises.push(picRef.getDownloadURL())
   })

   const urls = await Promise.all(promises);

   for(let url of urls){
      imgArr.push(<img src={url} alt="pics" />)
   }

   this.setState({images : imgArr})  
}
```

Comment: Appreciate this nice working solution but I want to added that please avoid putting components directly into state, please check my answer @Vasu Ch

Comment: you are right, I was just solving the current problem with minimal changes :)